# Possible loss of precision; extracting char from string

Tags: java, type-conversion

I am getting a string from the user and then doing some checking to make sure it is valid, here is the code I have been using;

```
char digit= userInput.charAt(0) - '0';
```

This had been working fine until I did some work on another method, I went to compile and have been receiving a 'possible loss of precision' error since then.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your subtraction, even when it is cast correctly, will be reducing the char values 0, 1, 2...9 to binary 0, 1, 2...9. Any value below '0' will actually become negative but char is an unsigned value. What you are trying to do is not valid and does not make sense. Use what cletus is suggesting. See my answer if you really want to do this.

Answer (score 6):

For one thing you should be using the [`Character`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) methods for doing this rather than a home grown solution, namely [`Character.isDigit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit(char)) for checking validity and [`Character.digit()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)) for getting a value:

```
char c = ...
if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
  // it's a digit
}
int value = Character.digit(c, 10);
```

Why you're getting this warning is explained by [5.6.2 Binary Numeric Promotion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#170983) from the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/jTOC.doc.html):

> When an operator applies *binary
>   numeric promotion* to a pair of
>   operands, each of which must denote a
>   value of a numeric type, the following
>   rules apply, in order, using widening
>   conversion ([§5.1.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/conversions.doc.html#25214)) to convert
>   operands as necessary:
>
> - If either operand is of type `double`, the other is converted to
>     `double`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `float`, the other is converted
>     to `float`.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type `long`, the other is converted to
>     `long`.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type `int`.

So what's happening is that when you do the subtraction both arguments are being promoted to `int`s. The result is an `int`. When you try and assign that `int` to a `char` there is a possible loss of precision (32 bit signed to 16 bit unsigned).

An alternative validation technique is simply to use a regular expression:

```
if (s.matches("\\d\\d-\\d\\d")) {
  // it's ##-##
}
```

or, if you need to grab the groups:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d\\d)-(\\d\\d)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // first group
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // second group
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I am checking to make sure the user enters a string in the format digitdigit-digitdigit, if it doesn't match this, or the numbers are outside of the range I am checking then I want to return an error.

Comment: @Troy why not use a regex of say `\d\d-\d\d` and testing the user input for that? If not, using `Character.isDigit()` can do the verification you want.

Answer (score 0):

Java may be converting `userInput.charAt(0)` and `'0'` to a different datatype before doing the subtraction, then converting back afterwards.

Try explicitly casting the result to `char` before storing it into digit:

```
char digit = (char)(userInput.charAt(0) - '0');
```

Comment: @Troy: `digit` has to be assigned a value, it is a primitive type. Is the value binary 0? That would make sense if the charAt(0) was a '0'.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with how Java implicitly casts operands when used with arithmetic operators.

Both `userInput.charAt(0)` and `'0'` are of type `char` but they are implicitly converted to integers for the operation (subtraction) and hence when the integer result is assigned to a `char`, Java will given an error.

Answer (score 0):

You really should use cletus' answer and I gave him +1. However, if you really want to use that subtraction in your code you should not store the result in a `char` at all, since the result can be negative (if the user enters " " (space) for instance).

```
int digit = userInput.charAt(0) - '0';
if (digit < 0 || digit > 9)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad input at 0, must be between 0 and 9.");
```

Of course, this should not have a hard coded index either unless you really just want to 
check the first position of that string.